# Text Mining of Non-Isolated words

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I have a dataset (one very long column from a PostgresDB) where the data is saved in the following way:

```
**Variable_1** 
honey-pot 
treesarecool 
this-is-my-honeypot 
thisismyhonepot 
honey-is-sweet 
treesfurniture 
honeybees-production 
themoonisgone 
tableproduction
```

Sometimes words stand isolated, like *"honey"* for example, sometimes they are part of a longer word like *"honeypot"* or *"honeybees"*. I ultimately want a frequency table with the most frequent words like this.:

```
Frequency Table: 
Honey     4 
trees     2 
Table     1 
pot       1 
namek     1
gone      1 
furniture 1 
his       n 
are       n 
pro       n 
duc       n 
tio       n 
...     ...
```

I DO NOT have a list of specific words to look for (I would use grep() in this case). I have no experience in text mining, but after some research I figured out that most text mining tools like (tm) need words to be isolated *("The honey is sweet")* in order to be able to aggregate and analyze them. So I figured that what Im looking for is a tool which uses brute force to compare strings. Like, find all similar strings longer than 3 characters (characterized in the frequency table by "n".

Is my assumption correct? Is there a tool in R that can accomplish this? Any other ideas, suggestions?

Appreciations!

**Update 1**

Having tried out the solution by Adam for a week now, I can make the following recomendations for analyzing strings like the ones mentioned above:

1. Removing all "-", "_" and "." greatly helps reducing the number of irrelevant/uninteresting ngrams. Im interested in finding the frequency of a given word in my database and these signs don't contribute anything to such an analysis and instead just inflate the resulting dataset.
2. Removing Numbers [0-9] also hels reducing the amount of ngrams. Unless you also want the frequency of specific numbers (like 0041 predial codes or such ...). I would remove them and make a separate number analysis later (by removing all characters and signs and just leaving numbers). But it highly depends what your goal is!
3. Clean your Data!!! This is my first analysis of strings and my most important takeaway is that clean data, as always, goes a long way in reaching your goal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `quanteda` package to `tokenize()` each word into a set of character ngrams & then tabulate the results.

The below code iterates through the words and splits them into ngrams of lengths in the range: `[3, nchar(word)]`.

The size of the `char_ngrams` object will grow pretty quickly as the number of input words increases.  So not sure how well this will scale.

```
library(quanteda)

#create exapmle data
words = c("honey-pot",
          "treesarecool",
          "this-is-my-honeypot",
          "thisismyhonepot",
          "honey-is-sweet",
          "treesfurniture",
          "honeybees-production",
          "themoonisgone",
          "tableproduction")

#perform char ngram tokenization
char_ngrams = unlist(
  lapply(words, function(w) {
    unlist(
      tokenize(w,
               "character",
               ngrams=3L:nchar(w),
               conc="")
      )
    })
)

#show most popular character ngrams
head(sort(table(char_ngrams), decreasing = TRUE))
#char_ngrams
# one   hon  hone honey   ney  oney 
# 6     5     5     4     4     4
```